# In practice, is there any "lazy" evalution in multiplication with zero in run time

Tags: c++, c

Will the machine or compiler make use of the property that zero multiplied with an integer must always be zero? Consider

```
int f(int c, int d, int e, int f)
{
    // some complex calculations here...
}

int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f)
{
    return (a - b) * f(c, d, e, f);
}
```

In run time, if we pass some arguments where `a == b`, then mathematically there is no need to calculate the result of `f()` (assuming no undefined or strange behavior). The result must always be 0.

I am not quite sure if there is any possibility that the machine / compiler might use some optimizing technique to skip the calculation of `f()`. Or, asked the other way round, is it guaranteed that `f()` will be always called no matter what values of `a` and `b` are?

*I am tagging this question with both C and C++ to avoid the slight chance that rules differ in C and C++ in this case. If so, please elaborate respectively.*

**Update** Thanks for the discussion. From what I gather up to now, the possible existence of a function's side-effect would certainly be a factor to consider. However, I would like to clarify that the helper function `f()` is not a must in my intention. Code like

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f)
{
    return (a - b) * /* some complex expression with c, d, e, f */;
}
```

would also qualify. Apologies for not making it clear at the beginning.

Comment: I'm sure compilers will try to keep a program 'printing' the greeting ... `int f(int a, int b, int c, int d) { printf("%s\n", "hi"); /* and some complex calculations */ }`

Comment: This should not be shortcircuiting even if you hardcode zero there. Finding reference would be harder.

Comment: if you don't want `f` to be called when `a == b`, then you need to code that in yourself.  Otherwise the compiler is going to generate code that calls the function and does the multiplication.  AFAIK, The compiler isn't going to generate a branch like that, especially if `f` has observable side effects.

Comment: You can ask  another interesting question - is the compiler allowed to optimize `f(x)*a + f(x)*b` into `f(x)*(a+b)`. I would say no, as the compiler does not know if `f` has any side-effects.

Comment: The compiler is required to call `f` for its side effects. If it can prove that `f` has no side effects, then it could in principle optimize for the case `a==b`, but such an optimization is not required by the standard (and is in practice unlikely unless the compiler has other clues that `a` and `b` are equal a high percentage of the time).

Comment: I would recommend compiling this code in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) and looking at the assembly generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Compiler

The compiler usually (meaning most compilers) optimizes arithmetic calculations if they consist of constants. For example `i = 1 + 3;` will be optimized to `i = 4;` but the more complex the calculation, fewer the compilers that will be able to optimize it. Compilers usually work recursively with tree structures and search them to find possible optimizations. So it makes no difference if you add 2 or 20 constants, but it makes a difference if the additions are inside a loop. In this case calling `foo(a, a, x, y, z);` is a bit less likely to be optimized that calling `foo(1, 1, x, y, z);`.

If the compiler first inlines small functions, and searches for arithmetic optimizations after, then it is quite likely that if the parameters are determined at compile time, the compiler will be able to optimize out all the extra instructions. After all this is what it boils down to, can the compiler be sure that the result of foo is 0 without running the program?

Two things to note:

- Compilers can selectively optimize different things (for gcc using -O0, -O1, -O2, -O3 and other more specific commands)
- Compilers themselves are written programmes and not a magic black box. For the compiler to optimize foo, a developer must write somewhere in there: check if a subtraction is about the same variable and if so substitute the result with 0. And somewhere near that: check if you multiply with zero and substitute that with 0. All that at compile time.

For the compiler to optimize at run time, then instead of multiplying a and b, the produced assembly will contain checks for each variable to check for any one zeros. I don't think any compiler does that.

### Processor

The processor is for the most part a dumb machine that does exactly what its told. The multiplication is done by hardware that carries some bitwise logic. For the processor to optimize this multiplication, the circuits that do that calculation must also have a part that says the following: if one of the multiplicants is 0 then the result is 0 and we need not do the multiplication. If someone has programmed the processor to do that, then it is optimized. Depends on implementation but I think it's quite unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

This would require the compiler to generate branching, which it generally doesn't like to do. If you want the branching, make it explicit:

```
int f(int c, int d, int e, int f)
{
    // some complex calculations here...
}

int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f)
{
    if (a == b) return 0;
    return (a - b) * f(c, d, e, f);
}
```

As noted in the comments, `f` may also have side effects, in which case it is guaranteed not to be "optimized" away.

Comment: The main problem is not branching, but the fact that `f()` might have side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the compiler can determine, at compile time, that `(a - b)` will always evaluate to 0, it won't try to add code to perform the evaluation at runtime.

The main reason is what it has been discussed in other answers: the function that provides one of the operands can have side effects, and you don't normally want to avoid them to happen (if you would want it, you would have to add the evaluation by yourself).

The other reason is that the hardware already does that, and multiplications in which one of the operands is 0 normally takes much less cycles than a regular one.

Note that this is different to what happens with short circuit evaluation in conditional expressions: `if ( (a - b) == 0 || f(c, d, e, f) == 0 )` . In this case, the first condition may avoid the second one from executing `f()` at runtime.

Comment: Indeed, in the original code, even if the compiler can prove that `a-b` will always evaluate to zero, it will still call `f` (or at least generate code that has exactly the same effect as if `f` were called).  The result would be something like `f(c,d,e,f); return 0;`.

Comment: Is there any info on how much faster multplication with a zero operand can be in common architectures? Another answer here called it "quite unlikely", but you say it's "normal". So, a quick reference/benchmark would be appreciated :-)

Comment: This used to be common when mulitply was a slow operation, but these days on most hardware mulitply is very fast (much faster than a branch mispredict), so there's not much point to an early out for a 0.  You can refer to https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf for far more information on how fast various operations are than you can possibly absorb.

Comment: I may have misread my info, and this actually may appliy to floating point multiplication, not integer one.

Comment: Re “Unless the compiler can determine, at compile time, that (a - b) will always evaluate to 0, it won't try to add code to perform the evaluation at runtime”: This is an overly broad statement. It may be true for observed behavior of compilers to date, but I doubt any have stated it as a policy. Certainly there are cases where compilers may compare pointers to choose to dispatch to different code based on whether arrays overlap (as the vectorization opportunities vary depending on overlap). It would not be unreasonable for a compiler to elide a call conditionally.